# Negating a perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl, negate

```
my ($INV_NB, $USAGE)=split /\|/,"9998|999999999999999";

if ($USAGE=~/^\d{15}\b/)
{
  print "\nUSAGE is Valid\n";
  print "length of $USAGE is ",length($USAGE);  
}
```

This worked as expected, but how can I negate this regexp? say if usage is not `/^\d{15}\b/`

```
if ($USAGE!=~/^\d{15}\b/)
{
  print "\nUSAGE is Invalid\n";
  print "length of $USAGE is ",length($USAGE);  
}
```

I tried this, but it isnt working ..

Comment: There's `unless (EXPR) BLOCK` too, which *may* make the meaning more obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
if ($USAGE !~ /^\d{15}\b/)
```

---

[Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators):

> Binary "!~" is just like "=~" except
>   the return value is negated in the
>   logical sense.

Comment: Or you can do `unless ($USAGE=~/^\d{15}\b/)` or `if (not $USAGE=~/^\d{15}\b/)`

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct, but if you ever want to negate a regex (and not the operator that applies it), you can use

```
/^(?!.*?$regex_to_be_negated)/s
```

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
unless ($USAGE=~/^\d{15}\b/)
{
  print "\nUSAGE is Invalid\n";
  print "length of $USAGE is ",length($USAGE);  
}
```